# first half works but second half doesn't store any value

Tags: java, arrays

```
 public class Palindrome
{
public static boolean isDoublePalindrome (char[] digits)
{
    char[] firstHalf = new char[digits.length/2];
    char[] secondHalf = new char[digits.length/2];

    for(int a = 0; a < digits.length / 2; a++)
    {
        firstHalf[a] = digits[a];
        System.out.print(firstHalf[a]);
    }

    for(int b = digits.length / 2; b < digits.length; b++)
    {
        secondHalf[b] = digits[b];
    }

    if(digits.length % 2 == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < digits.length / 2 - 1; i++)
        {
            if(digits[i] != digits[digits.length - i - 1])
            {
                return false;
            }

            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < firstHalf.length / 2 - 1; j++)
        {
            if(firstHalf[j] != firstHalf[digits.length - j - 1])
            {
                return false;
            }

            else 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    else if(digits.length % 2 != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

Here I take `digits[]` as parameter and whatever the character array in there I want to divide them into half and store first half into firstHalf and second half into secondHalf array. But when I debug, secondHalf doesn't have any values. Please help!!

Comment: That's a crazy way to check for isPalindrome. You only need one single for loop that counts from 0 to the middle of the string length, not four for loops. You could just compare first char to last char, then second to char to second-to-last char, and so on. If one comparison fails then it's false.

Comment: Would like to see your debug output ... looks to me like you are just printing first half as it is made, but forgot the print statement for second half.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

method to do so

```
public int reverse(int num) {
    int revNum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        int rem = num % 10;
        revNum = (revNum * 10) + rem;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return revNum;
}
```

implementation

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    int num = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
    String str = scanner.next();

    Palindrome palin = new Palindrome();
    int revNum = palin.reverse(num);

    if (num == revNum) {
        System.out.printf("\n The number %d is a Palindrome ", num);
    } else {
        System.out.printf("\n The number %d is not a Palindrome ", num);
    }
```

here palindrome is class name of main method hope my works helps you in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

First off, be careful dividing your array length by 2, you may have an odd length (making one half 1 longer than the other).

What happens if "digits" is an odd number length? It can still be a palindrome.

To answer your question, in the second loop your assigning values to secondHalf[b], which is past it's length: "digits.length / 2". You should be assigning values into secondHalf[] starting at zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lazy, this could be your way:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s){
    String reverse = new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

And if you are not allowed to cheat, this could help you:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s){
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length / 2; i++){
        if(Character.toLowerCase(chars[i]) !=  Character.toLowerCase(chars[chars.length - 1 - i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

EDIT: With the second version you also don't encounter the problem of overlooking a character, because if it is a odd number, it would be the middle character that both sides of the string share.